# Почему не работает яндекс метрика?

Tags: javascript, yandex-metrika-api, яндекс-метрика

Есть событие, которые вызывается при инициализации метрики. Собственно тут более подробно об этом ['метрика'](https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/code/counter-initialize.xml). По каким-то причинам, событие не отрабатывает, инициализировать метрику в браузере руками можно, след. способом `yaMetrika.initedCallback()`

```js
var yandexId = 44034219;

YandexMetrika = function (document) {

    if (window.yandexMetrika) {
        return window.yandexMetrika;
    }

    window.yandexMetrika = {
        // Очередь событий
        queue: [],

        client: null,

        initialized: false,

        // Инициализация
        initedCallback: function () {
            this.initialized = true;
            this.client = new Ya.Metrika({
                id: yandexId,
                clickmap: true,
                trackLinks: true,
                accurateTrackBounce: true,
                ut: "noindex"
            });

            $.each(this.queue, function (i, goal) {
                this.client.reachGoal(goal);
            });
        },

        // Отправка события
        goal: function (goal) {
            this.initialized ? this.client.reachGoal(goal) : this.queue.push(goal);
        }
    };

    var n = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    var f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n) };

    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";
    if (window.opera == "[object Opera]") {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
    } else {
        f();
    }

    return window.yandexMetrika;
};

var yaMetrika = YandexMetrika(document);

$(document).on('yandex_metrika_callbacks', function () {
    console.log('ol');
    yaMetrika.initedCallback();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h1>test</h1>

    <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function (d, w, c) {
            (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
                try {
                    w.yaCounter44034219 = new Ya.Metrika({
                        id:44034219,
                        clickmap:true,
                        trackLinks:true,
                        accurateTrackBounce:true
                    });
                } catch(e) { }
            });

            var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
                    s = d.createElement("script"),
                    f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.async = true;
            s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

            if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
                d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
            } else { f(); }
        })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
    </script>
    <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/44034219" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
    <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Что бы вызывалось событие инциализации добавьте счетчику параметр **triggerEvent: true** . 
А дальше как в инструкции

```js
jQuery(document).on('yacounterXXXXXinited', function () {
    console.log('счетчик yaCounterXXXXX можно использовать');
});
```